# Iterating between two layers using QGIS python

Tags: pyqgis, buffer, iterator

I will try and explain my situation as clearly as possible.

I just created my first plugin that is being used to analyze between various layers and give back quantities to the user. Most of it is straight forward until I have to try and involve two layers.

I have a point layer. With that point layer, I want to create a "buffer" of 10' and use that buffer as an intersect to analyze a polyline layer if it is within range. Once that buffer detects said polyline layer, I want to be able to read from multiple fields attributes to see if they meet a certain criteria. If that criteria is met, then that point will be selected.

To further explain, the point layer represents Assets (eg. Power pole, XFMR, Pedestal, Fuse Pad, etc.). If that asset is a Proposed Pole, I want to create a 10'"buffer". If that buffer intersects one of our Proposed Conductors, I want to to be able to analyze that Proposed Conductor and know whether or not it is a Single Phase or Three phase conductor. If it meets my criteria, I want the code to be able to select that feature (Proposed Power Pole).

What I am creating with this plugin is a Payline schedule. So once the designers are done designing, they will click my magic button for all of their results.

I am running QGIS version 2.0.1

My main goal would be to create the buffer at a point feature and return the polylines within that 10' radius.

Comment: Adam, There is a LOT of items in your question, which is basically asking how to do everything you want.  Can you narrow it down? Otherwise the answer will be very long.

Comment: I would suggest breaking your research into smaller steps, 1. figure out how to buffer point feature, 2. figure out how to select by location (buffer feature intersects line feature), 3. figure out how to iterate through selected features and pull attributes...etc